# How do I use "testrpc --account"?

Tags: accounts, testrpc

I'm trying to create an initialization script for testrpc that creates specific accounts with specific balances at start up.

```
testrpc  --debug -account="aa73b5c98e60d589e71ce7cff59c02f82e12c7ce676ee356da8e058a285ccd61,100000"
```

generates the following

```
testrpc  --debug --account="aa73b5c98e60d589e71ce7cff59c02f82e12c7ce676ee356da8e058a285ccd61,100000"
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var Module;if(!Module)Module=(typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:null)||{};var moduleOverrides={};for(var key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&typeof require==="function"&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE){if(!Module["print"])Module["print"]=function print(x){process["stdout"].write(x+"\n")};if(!Module["printErr"])Module["printErr"]=function printErr(x){process["stderr"].write(x+"\n")};var nodeFS=require("fs");var nodePath=require("path");Module["read"]=function read(filename,binary){filename=nodePath["normalize"](filename);var ret=nodeFS["readFileS

RangeError: private key length is invalid
    at RangeError (native)
    at Object.exports.privateToPublic (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/index.js:356:20)
    at StateManager.createAccount (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/lib/statemanager.js:155:25)
    at Array.map (native)
    at StateManager.initialize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/lib/statemanager.js:71:33)
    at new GethApiDouble (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/lib/subproviders/geth_api_double.js:21:14)
    at Object.Interface.provider (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/lib/interface.js:148:25)
    at Object.Interface.server (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/lib/interface.js:29:25)
    at Object.TestRPC.server (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/index.js:5:22)
    at Object
```

The private key I'm using was generated in the previous run of testrpc as a test account:

## Available Accounts

> (0) 0x22ddfe3c6439839edf8e2e56126c65c5fc5a2f40 (1)
>   0xc1da5556ecfc0ac4168d60bc8c884ae3dd6fba3f (2)
>   0xb234a0c1afbd20e1f9a117272136aeaafaccb614 (3)
>   0xc8c206e296e92a475ee4c2bf9fb8d00d7ac83876 (4)
>   0x8b22109f827a7d6b16b085f9755e23a124a21709 (5)
>   0x34cb6cc7cc29f6ce978521ad691716fd7a3809c8 (6)
>   0xa3b692025e76530506a232188b6ecd681027585e (7)
>   0x9b5a29122e80f8975d50a031b21e88adae489cf4 (8)
>   0xa921ef355a7d2729e7674a081aeeceff28419e23 (9)
>   0x444a798fad3ef318bfd7cee26c5937298cc2cbec

## Private Keys

> (0) aa73b5c98e60d589e71ce7cff59c02f82e12c7ce676ee356da8e058a285ccd61
>   (1) 2337bf7968f70bcc7b1c04aba780b6157c3db9c575481c19e90f347f50c5df95
>   (2) 8d5cd323b43ee0fe3c3073bbbfa174d682ac8564164b2f253111ee591323a4f4
>   (3) fccb97187708748a88c7dd7419c63fa3f5c125826116827f5459c72c2a07cd2a
>   (4) 032b517d15b77d0e8d8611beeb3e43021637c37fc4a6efcc40e6fa2fe0e20850
>   (5) d5af034aa8990068eee4581012a4010fb78220293464ac3e39ca40f9cb79a873
>   (6) 9767f461cc6a1a0688e570846618547de95955d2bfeb37746c6997b7257e156e
>   (7) dc6a7f0cd30f86da5e55ca7b62ac1a86f5d8b76a796176152803e0fcbc253900
>   (8) 52f3a1fa15405e1d5a68d7774ca45c7a3c7373a66c3c44db94a7f99a22c14d28

I have also tried to use a HEX balance instead of an integer and got the same result.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 4):

Per [the testrpc Readme](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/blob/master/README.md) you need a 0x stuck on the front of the private key.

Answer (score 2):

```
testrpc  --debug -account="0xaa73b5c98e60d589e71ce7cff59c02f82e12c7ce676ee356da8e058a285ccd61,100000"
```

add 0x prefix